# Pycairo - Get SVG in bytes without saving it in a file

Tags: python, svg, cairo, pycairo

Actually I was using pycairo for generating svg's but the problem is that i want the svg in form of bytes. which can be later used. With Imagesurface i can do it because it has function called surface_to_png() but with SVG surface i am unable to do it also coverting surface object or getting data from it not possible.
Please suggest any way.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

No idea if / how PyCairo exposes this, but the cairo API you are looking for is "write by calling a function with the data to write": https://www.cairographics.org/manual/cairo-SVG-Surfaces.html#cairo-svg-surface-create-for-stream